# oracle::occi::ResultSet::next() crashes my program

Tags: c++, oracle, occi

I have a 64 bits C++ server application running on windows 7 and when it does a select on the database and calls next() on the result set the process simply dies, no exceptions, no dumps and no debug info after ResultSet->next(). Writes on the database works with no problems and both reads and writes works on the 32 bit version

I'm using the 11.2 version of the win64 oracle libraries that came with instant client and SDK

EDIT: it's the simplest of codes

```
const std::string sql("select * from schedule_import");

std::auto_ptr<IRecordSet> query = m_conn->Open(sql);

while(query->Next()) // dies
{
  const std::string key(query->GetField("bean_key"));
  //...
```

IRecordSet is just an interface for common functions of DB drivers like next, getField and it's implemented in here

```
bool OracleRecordSet::Next()
{
  return m_pResultSet->next() != NULL; //crashes here
}
```

where m_pResultSet is a oracle::occi::ResultSet*

Comment: Can you post your code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trys my problem is solved.

I was linking my debug program to oraocci11.lib because I didn't have the debug version and I thought it didn't matter much. After a bit of search I've found the debug version of the library, oraocci11d.lib, with the corresponding dll and the crash is gone

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiared with Oracle API, but question is if m_pResultSet is not NULL (in case of segmentation fault) and if there is no exception (in case of abort(), raise() stack).

BR!