# ResultSet ->getString() crashes when value is >=16

Tags: c++, mysql, crash, database-connection, mysql-connector

```
ResultSet *search;
....
....
search= prepareStatement->executeQuery();


while (search->next())
{
cout << "Email Found: " << search->getString("EmailColumn") << endl; //crashes here
}
```

From the code above, calling **getString()** function actually **gets** the value from the database. But then it crashes the program. It **displays** the value then **crashes** the program.

I **discovered** the **problem** but **couldn't** **fix** it. I can't tell if this is a **bug** or **something else**.

The problem only happens when the **length** of the value in the EmailColumn **column** is **more** or **equals** to **16**. **No** error if the **length** of the value is **less** or **equals** to **15**.

Any solution or workarounds for this?

Comment: Well ... easiest workaround would be to use strings with max. length of 15 in your DB. Just kidding ;) ...... Is the ResultSet class a self written class? If so ... does it have a char-Array for storing the returned string from DB and is this char-Array limited to 16?

Comment: ResultSet is not wriiten by me. It is from Oracle and is sued to read the values returned from the Database after querying the database. getString seems to be the only way to get string from database.

Comment: Code looks OK. But I don't see ResultSet::getString overload that takes string as argument in Oracle Documentation (I'm not familiar with a library, so just check it). Also check whether you are linking correct lib, as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803306/oracleocciresultsetnext-crashes-my-program

Comment: As nikitoz, I could not find any such overloaded function in the OCCI library. If you are using OCCI, I would suggest to add "occi" to your tags. Otherwise ... give us a hint, where this class comes from.

Comment: There are a number of questions on SO related to problems with ResultSet::getString(), with different causes. Did you try the fixes suggested in any of those questions? E.g.: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15832958/mysql-c-connector-crashes-my-app-at-resultset-getstring) , (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014069/res-getstring-crashes-the-application) , (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822958/mysql-c-connector-getstring-doesnt-work-correctly-while-getint-works-perfe)

Comment: @Mr.Yellow-, I am using MySQL Connector/C++. It comes with those libraries. I hope that explains where the classes came from to you.  nikitoz, there is a function with string overload. I can see the function here on the header files and it compiles. It works but not when the length is more or equals to 16. Also, the latest c++ tutorial on oracle website used getString(string) and no other function to retrieve strings. lonut, I tried those but none fixed the problem. Just by reading their problems, it seems like their problems are different with mine.

Comment: Are you using varchar for your DB-column? Then ... this might help you: http://www.codeitive.com/0HmjkjkVWg/mysql-c-connector-crashes-my-app-at-resultset%3Egetstring.html        ... using getBlob() instead

Comment: I have tried that too. getBlob crashes too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. The solution is to build your own C++ Connector and use the dll files it compiles. The dll distributed by Oracle was made with a different version of Visual Studio compiler that I am currently using. The first answer here will show you how to build it yourself. [MySQL Connector C++ 64bit build from source in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20281360/mysql-connector-c-64bit-build-from-source-in-visual-studio-2012/30319071)?

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same problem (and realized too late that Oracle is not supporting the library for Windows anymore). The following workaround worked for me:

```
ResultSet *search;
....
....
search= prepareStatement->executeQuery();

while( search->next() )
{
  string const * theString = 
    new string( search->getString( "EmailColumn") );

  cout << *theString << endl;

  operator delete( theString );
  theString = nullptr;
}
```

My guess is that by this construction VisualStudio 2015 is compiling code that is not calling the destructor std::string::~string() (which caused the crash for my application) for a string that is created by the library via ResultsSet::getString().